# I cannot get the filepath while in GUI window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I couldn't able to get file's path in filePath variable while the GUI is executing, I could able to get it after closing the GUI window. I want to get the file's path while the GUI is still on, How do I do it?

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

filePath = ""

def browsefunc():
    global filePath
    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

browsebutton = Button(window, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
browsebutton.pack()

pathlabel = Label(window)
pathlabel.pack()

print("File Path (Before mainloop) : %s"%filePath)

window.mainloop()

print("File Path (After mainloop) : %s"%filePath)
```

Comment: Your code seems fine when you press the button and select a new file the `filePath` would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code :).
I created following example that shows, that the path exists while the GUI is being executed:

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os

filePath = ""

def browsefunc():
    global filePath
    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def delete():
    os.remove(filePath)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

browsebutton = Button(window, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
deleteButton = Button(window, text="Delete", command=delete)
browsebutton.pack()
deleteButton.pack()
pathlabel = Label(window)
pathlabel.pack()

print("File Path (Before mainloop) : %s"%filePath)

window.mainloop()

print("File Path (After mainloop) : %s"%filePath)
```

The program simple deletes a browsed file and it does work.

But I cannot explain to you why you can't print the file path.

Friendly Greetings

Danilo Jakob

Comment: The reason why  `filePath` cannot be printed while the GUI is running is because the print statement is outside the mainloop, and therefore is only executed when the mainloop ends, i.e. when the GUI is closed. But if one replaces the `os.remove(filePath)` in the `delete()` function by `print(filePath)` the path will be printed each time the delete button is clicked.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your precization @j_4321. Makes the answer more complete.